# Python logging not outputting lower levels without basicConfig

Tags: python, logging

The below code doesn't output `test` like intended.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug('test')
```

The solution is to add a `logging.basicConfig()` to the top of the file. Why is this specifically? To my understanding `basicConfig` only sets up a stream handler and formatter for the **root** logger. But I am instantiating a new logger, `logging.getLogger('foo')`, so I'm not sure how the root logger affects this new logger.

Conversely, I can understand how the below code doesn't need a `basicConfig` since you're setting up a handler and formatter for the new logger, `logging.getLogger('my_logger')`

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
f_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.info('test')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output is done by handlers, and you either have to add a handler manually (as in your second snippet) or use `basicConfig()` to add one to the root logger. If no handler is configured by you, [an internal "handler of last resort" is used](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided), whose level is set to `WARNING` (so it won't output `DEBUG` or `INFO` messages).

Comment: I see, so it checks:
1. If the logger has a handler use it
2. If the logger has no handler use the root logger's handler (set by basicConfig())
3. If the root logger has no handler (basicConfig() is not called), use the handler of last resort

Comment: @meghidey No, if _no handlers found in the logged-to-logger or its ancestors_, the handler of last resort is used.